# Split field and insert rows in SQL Server trigger, when mutliple rows are affected without using a cursor

Tags: sql-server, split, triggers, database-cursor

I have an `INSERT` trigger of a `table`, where one field of the `table` contains a comma-separated list of key-value pairs, that are separated by a `:`

I can select this field with the two values into a temp table easily with this statement:

```
-- SAMPLE DATA FOR PRESENTATION ONLY
    DECLARE @messageIds VARCHAR(2000) = '29708332:55197,29708329:54683,29708331:54589,29708330:54586,29708327:54543,29708328:54539,29708333:54538,29708334:62162,29708335:56798';
    
    SELECT
            SUBSTRING(value, 1,CHARINDEX(':', value) - 1)AS MessageId,
            SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX(':', value) + 1, LEN(value)-SUBSTRING(value,0,CHARINDEX(value,':'))) AS DeviceId
            INTO #temp_messages
            FROM STRING_SPLIT(@messageIds, ',')
            SELECT * FROM #temp_messages 
            DROP TABLE #temp_messages
```

The result will look like this

```
29708332    55197
29708329    54683
29708331    54589
29708330    54586
29708327    54543
29708328    54539
29708333    54538
29708334    62162
29708335    56798
```

From here I can `join` the temp `table` to other tables and `insert` some of the results into a third `table`.

Inside the trigger I can get the `messageIds` with a simple `SELECT` statement like

```
DECLARE @messageIds VARCHAR(2000) = (SELECT ProcessMessageIds FROM INSERTED)
```

Now I create the temp `table` (like described above) and process my

```
INSERT INto <new_table> SELECT col1, col1, .. FROM #temp_messages
JOIN <another_table> ON ...
```

Unfortunately this will only work for single row inserts. As soon as there is more than one row, my `SELECT ProcessMessageIds FROM INSERTED` will fail, as there are multiple rows in the INSERTED table.

I can process the rows in a CURSOR but as far as I know CURSORS are a no-go in triggers and I should avoid them whenever it is possible.

Therefore my question is, if there is another way to do this without using a CURSOR inside the `trigger`?

Comment: *"where one field of the table contains a comma separated list of keyvalue"* this is the real problem; fix your design and normalise your data

Comment: As for the issue, write a set-based trigger; don't assume that an `INSERT` only ever contains one row: [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) & [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) (Though this does not change my statement about fixing the design.)

Comment: You know that you don't *have to* select processmessageIds into a variable? One can work with the inserted table directly? like: insert into #t select substring(...) from inserted cross apply string_split(somecolumn, ',') s

Comment: @Larnu You're absolutely right, but it is a 3rd party software, that writes this string (coming from an API call) to this field of the database. That's the reason, why I try to "normalize" in a trigger and write the single values to a different table ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get into the details of the solution, let me point out that you would have no such issues if you normalized your database, as @Larnu pointed out in the comment section of your question.

Your

```
DECLARE @messageIds VARCHAR(2000) = (SELECT ProcessMessageIds FROM INSERTED)
```

statement assumes that there will be a single value to be assigned to `@messageIDs` and, as you have pointed out, this is not necessarily true.

**Solution 1**: Join with `INSERTED` rather than load it into a variable

```
INSERT INTO t1
SELECT ...
FROM t2
JOIN T3
ON ...
JOIN INSERTED
ON ...
```

and then you can reach `INSERTED.ProcessMessageIds` without issues. This will no longer assume that a single value was used.

**Solution 2**: cursors

You can use a `CURSOR`, as you have already pointed out, but it's not a very good idea to use cursors inside a trigger, see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87fd1205-4e27-413d-b040-047078b07756/cursor-usages-in-trigger-in-sql-server?forum=aspsqlserver

**Solution 3**: insert a single line at a time

While this would not require a change in your `trigger`, it would require a change in how you insert and it would increase the number of db requests necessary, so I would advise you not to choose this approach.

**Solution 4**: normalize

See https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/sql-tutorial/what-is-normalization-in-sql

If you had a proper table rather than a table of composite values, you would have no such issues and you would have a much easier time to process the message ids in general.

**Summary**

It would be wise to normalize your tables and perform the refactoring that would be needed afterwards. It's a great effort now, but you will enjoy its fruits. If that's not an option, you can "act as if it was normalized" and choose Solution 1.

Comment: For using your Solution 1, I have no Idea how to JOIN with a SELECT FROM STRING_SPLIT ...
And yes, data should be normalized, but I have no hold on how data is written to this column. This is the reason why I want to write the values in a table and "normalize" them in the trigger.

Comment: @siggemannen pointed it out above:
select substring(...) from inserted cross apply string_split(somecolumn, ',')
Thank you!

Comment: @Helmut just wanted to respond to your first comment, but you beat me to it :) I'm glad it was sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the answers, joining with the INSERTED table solved my problem.

```
SELECT INTAB.Id,
    SUBSTRING(value, 1,CHARINDEX(':', value) - 1)AS MessageId,
    SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX(':', value) + 1, LEN(value)-SUBSTRING(value,0,CHARINDEX(value,':'))) AS DeviceId
    FROM INSERTED AS INTAB
    CROSS APPLY  STRING_SPLIT(ProcessMessageids,',')
```

I never used "CROSS APPLY" before, thank you.